Variation of Chiral Plebanski Action for GR
In the Einstein-Cartan action for GR in the 'first-order' formalism, one has a solder-form $e^a$ together with a connection $A^{ab}$ assuming values in $\mathfrak{so}(1,3)$. The action
\begin{equation}
S[e,A] = \int \varepsilon_{abcd} e^a \wedge e^b \wedge R^{cd}(A)
\end{equation}
gives upon variation with respect to the solder form the Einstein equations in pure form notation (restricting ourselves to vacuum for clarity),
\begin{equation}
\epsilon_{abcd} e^b \wedge R^{cd} = 0
\end{equation}
The trick is to use the anti-symmetry in both the wedge product and Levi-Civita tensor to reduce the variation to
\begin{equation}
\delta_e S = 2 \int \delta e^a \wedge (\varepsilon_{abcd}e^b \wedge R^{cd}).
\end{equation}
Suppose now we have a spin structure, and that we wish to consider the spinor equivalent to the construction above. Then our solder forms are $\sigma^{A\dot{A}}$, while the connection $\omega^{AB}$ now assumes values in $\mathfrak{sl}(2,\mathbb{C})$, together with the complex conjugates. There is no longer a completely anti-symmetric tensor, and now the action of interest assumes the form
\begin{equation}
S[\sigma, \omega] = \int \sigma^A_{\; \dot{A}} \wedge \sigma^{B\dot{A}} \wedge F_{AB}(\omega).
\end{equation}
where there will be a conjugate element, and $F_{AB}(\omega)$ is the curvature of the connection.
Now, if we restrict ourselves to a "self-dual" theory, we need only take this action and compute its variation in $\sigma$ to obtain the Einstein equations. The result should be
\begin{equation}
\sigma^{A\dot{A}} \wedge F_A^{\; B} = 0,
\end{equation}
from which our previous Einstein equations can follow in a simple manipulation.
My difficulty is in obtaining this result from the variation principle. Its clear what should happen, but not quite how it happens. Clearly
\begin{equation}
\delta_{\sigma} S = \int (\delta \sigma^A_{\; \dot{A}} \wedge \sigma^{B\dot{A}} + \sigma^A_{\; \dot{A}} \wedge \delta \sigma^{B\dot{A}}) \wedge F_{AB}
\end{equation}
Previously, we had the Levi-Civita tensor to manipulate some indices. Here it's not possible. My initial thoughts were that we could re-label some indices and use the anti-symmetry of the wedge to get the integrand to something like
\begin{equation}
\delta \sigma^A_{\; \dot{A}} \wedge \sigma^{B\dot{A}} \wedge F_{AB} - \delta \sigma^{A \dot{A}} \wedge \sigma^B_{\; \dot{A}} \wedge F_{BA}
\end{equation}
The desired result could follow provided the following two points were true:
\begin{equation}
F_{AB} = F_{BA} \quad \& \quad \delta \sigma^{A\dot{A}} \wedge \sigma^B_{\; \dot{A}} = - \delta \sigma^A_{\; \dot{A}} \wedge \sigma^{B\dot{A}}
\end{equation}
or the opposite case. I do not know that either of these things are possible, nor could I prove them. If the curvature of the connection were symmetric, wouldn't that imply it is no longer valued in $\mathfrak{sl}(2,\mathbb{C})$? At the same time, the space of self-dual 2-forms should be spanned by symmetric spinor fields. It is also not possible to remove the anti-symmetry in favor of (say) $\epsilon^{AB}$, since the curvature is traceless. Clarification and any further references would be helpful.
Some references:

"Self-Duality in Classical Gravity" - Joseph Samuel (Recent Advances in General Relativity (Einstein Studies), Eds. Allen I. Janis, John R. Porter, Birkhauser, Boston, 1992, p72-84).
"Self-dual 2-forms and gravity" - Riccardo Capovilla et al. Class. Quantum Grav. 8 41 (1991).
"Formulations of General Relativity" - Kirill Krasnov, Cambridge University Press (2020)


As an update, I would like to note that $F_{AB}$ is indeed symmetric (it is the self-dual curvature), as can be verified by computing $[D_a,D_b] \epsilon_{AB} = 0$. In addition, the combination $\sigma^{A}_{; \dot{A}} \sigma^{B \dot{A}}$ is symmetric in $AB$ indices. It seems however I can only verify the second point without the minus, so something is wrong in my approach.

You still have to vary wrt the connection $\omega$, otherwise the connection does not need to be related to the soldering form (i.e. it could have torsion for instance).

@Void you are of course correct, but the variation in the connection proceeds much more simply (no tricks are required beyond what is done in the standard Einstein-Cartan theory), hence why the question was focused on the variation in the solder-form.

I believe I have now solved the problem. Focusing on the variation,
\begin{equation}
\delta_{\sigma} S = \int (\delta \sigma^{A}_{\; \dot{A}} \wedge \sigma^{B\dot{A}} + \sigma^{A}_{\; \dot{A}} \wedge \delta \sigma^{B\dot{A}}) \wedge F_{AB} 
\end{equation}
It's clear that we are required to show the two variations are equivalent. Using anti-symmetry of the Wedge product, first write
\begin{equation}
\delta_{\sigma} S = \int (\delta \sigma^{A}_{\; \dot{A}} \wedge \sigma^{B\dot{A}} - \delta \sigma^{B\dot{A}}\wedge \sigma^{A}_{\; \dot{A}}) \wedge F_{AB} 
\end{equation}
Now it is true that $F_{AB}$ is symmetric in spinor indices (it is the self-dual components of the curvature, this must be so) as can be seen by explicit computation of the commutator of covariant derivatives on the symplectic form $\epsilon_{AB}$ (which must vanish for the connection to assume values in $\mathfrak{sl}(2,\mathbb{C}))$. We now perform the re-labeling trick via this symmetry, and reduce the variation to
\begin{equation}
\delta_{\sigma} S = \int (\delta \sigma^{A}_{\; \dot{A}} \wedge \sigma^{B\dot{A}} - \delta \sigma^{A\dot{A}}\wedge \sigma^{B}_{\; \dot{A}}) \wedge F_{AB}. 
\end{equation}
It remains to be shown then that
\begin{equation}
\delta \sigma^{A\dot{A}}\wedge \sigma^{B}_{\; \dot{A}} = - \delta \sigma^{A}_{\; \dot{A}} \wedge \sigma^{B\dot{A}}
\end{equation}
This result is true and is the 'seesaw' trick of summed spinor indices. Explicitly
\begin{equation} 
\sigma^{A}_{\; \dot{A}}\wedge \sigma^{B \dot{A}} = (\epsilon_{\dot{A} \dot{B}} \sigma^{A\dot{B}})\wedge  (\epsilon^{\dot{A} \dot{C}} \sigma^B_{\; \dot{C}}) = -\sigma^{A\dot{B}}\wedge \sigma^{B}_{\; \dot{B}},
\end{equation}
where we have used the fact that the symplectic form satisfies the identity
\begin{equation}
\epsilon_{\dot{A}\dot{B}} \epsilon^{\dot{B} \dot{C}} = \delta^{\dot{B}}_{\dot{A}} = - \epsilon_{\dot{B}\dot{A}} \epsilon^{\dot{B} \dot{C}}.
\end{equation}
Putting everything together, the variation is
\begin{equation}
\delta_{\sigma} S = 2 \int \delta \sigma^{A}_{\; \dot{A}} \wedge \sigma^{B\dot{A}} \wedge F_{AB}
\end{equation}
from which the Einstein equations follow as stated.
